# On a new magento store, add to cart and review functionality works on localhost, but not remotely

Tags: javascript, magento, webserver, localhost, remote-server

After doing a clean install of Magento Community Edition (v. 1.7.0.2) in my local machine and loading it with sample data provided by Magento, I can browse reviews, add items to cart, etc., as expected.

However, when I follow the same steps on a live server, JS functionality does not work, neither in Chrome nor in Firefox (I have not tried other browsers). For instance, clicking on 'Add to Cart' on a product page gives me nothing but a console error ("Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined").

What is causing this behaviour, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems, that the common js files of Magento aren't loaded. There are many possible reasons. If I was in your situation first I would check the files permissions, please check this article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions If it doesn't work, can you refresh the Magento cache and also refresh the merged css and js files cache. Other possible reason is if you haven't upload all files to the server, so check if everything is fine in js folder of the Magento root folder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @ceckoslab. The file permissions are fine (though I went ahead and reset them), and I refreshed the cache. No luck. I'm sure I uploaded all the files to the server, because I'm running the same script on both machines to install Magento. In any case, the js folder has the same contents. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a chance to provide url to the staging store? If I can see inspect it will have a chance to say more.

Comment: I don't, sorry---it's only accessible from a private network, at least for now.

Comment: Can you take a loot at the source code of the generated page and to see what are the urls from where are loaded the js files? If you use FireBug you even can click on the urls and to see if they are loaded with 404 response code some othere response code.

Comment: They are all correctly under <store directory>/js/varien (or /lib, /prototype, etc. Example: <store url>/js/prototype/prototype.js), and served as text when I go to those URLs directly.

Comment: Is your js (and css) set in admin to be merged together? 
What happens if you set your localhost to behave as if it is the live host, e.g. with www.whatever.com as the site url and with www.whatever.com in the /etc/hosts (equivalent for your os)? Will it load then? If not you may want to grep your db and files for pathnames and url that aren't on live.

Comment: Quick one: Can you check if the file js/varien/form.js is loaded and can you paste somewhere the generated html code of the page ... for example in https://gist.github.com

Comment: @IRISIndigo, js and css were not set to be merged, but setting them to merge did not fix the problem.

Comment: ...and setting the localhost to behave as if it is the live host, as you suggest, works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague fixed this issue. There were two problems that were causing magento to fail on the live server:

- Missing dependencies for PHP (dom and gm) which Magento was not complaining about.
- A low memory limit in PHP. We needed to increase the memory_limit setting in /etc/php.ini (512M worked for us).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but it fixed my problem. What I did was I moved the javascript segment in view.phtml from under "the add-to-cart-wrapper" class to above it.

Like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                if(this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
        <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

I hoped this helped.